# ¿Cómo enviar archivos con axios y Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, php7, axios, vuetify

Estoy intentando subir archivos al servidor, enviándolos con axios. En el título aclaro que uso Vuetify, pues la etiqueta de formulario es un `v-form` y no un `form` como lo es "convencionalmente". Estuve indagando en foros anglosajones y encontré una posible respuesta:

```
axios.post(this.$store.state.ruta + 'recepcionAreasConocimiento.php', {actualizarAreaConocimiento: true, icono: this.editedItem.icono_area}, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}).then(response => {

    console.log(response.data);

});
```

Pero, en la consola, me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: Muestra del error en consola.]

Esto es lo que tengo en el servidor **(PHP)**:

[image: Cómo recibo el dato en el lado del servidor.]

Quisiera saber porqué da ese error y cómo podría enviar el archivo (independiente de su extensión) con axios, junto a los demás datos del formulario.

De antemano, agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, *todo* el código (incluido mensajes de error y advertencias) debe ir en formato texto. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes usar para enviar el archivo y llegue al servidor es por medio de FormData, ya que si enviar un archivo por medio de una estructura json, este no lo interpreta bien y cuando lo tratar de parsear, el contenido.

Para usar FormData y enviarlo al servidor seria de la siguiente forma:

// Envió de información al servidor

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('actualizarAreaConocimiento', true);
form.append('icono', this.editedItem.icono_area); // encapsula el archivo

axios.post(this.$store.state.ruta + 'recepcionAreasConocimiento.php', form, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Ya en servidor lo recibiría como si de un form html se tratara.

```
if ($_SERVE['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   $c = new controladorAreaConocimiento();
   if (isset($_POST['actualizarAreaConocimiento']) && actualizarAreaConocimiento == true ){
      $file = $_FILE['icono'] // ya podrías manejar el archivo normalmente
   }
}
```

Así podrías enviar el archivo, como comente al inicio, al enviar un archivo dentro de un json, el servidor no lo interpreta bien y al decodificarlo este se pierde y causa errores.

Comment: Lo había intentado antes. Gracias, pero ahora, con esas líneas, me aparece este error: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\redtt_sistema\recepcion\recepcionAreasConocimiento.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />

  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   window.close();

  </script>

Comment: Quité el exctract y simplemente ignoraba el if, como si el $_POST['actualizarAreaConocimiento'] no existiera.

Comment: Justo después del $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); he puesto var_dump($_POST) y me devolvió NULL.

Comment: como ya no envias un json, al hacer el decode de `file_get_contents("php://input")`, este retorna vacío, puedes ver lo que te envía si hacer un var_dump al `file_get_contents("php://input")` directamente sin usar el decode y no guardándolo en el $_POST.

Comment: Vale. Ahora sí. Muchísimas gracias. Califico tu respuesta.